# How to train a CNN to differentiate between HTML objects(foreground) and the background in a screenshot of a webpage using caffe?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, convolution, conv-neural-network

I am working on a problem wherein I am trying to train a neural network to detect various html objects like textbox, radiobutton, button and dropdown list in a given snapshot of a webpage. I am supplying patches generated out of sliding window operation on the 1500 images (Training set) to my CNN for training.The label set is a 5 channel matrix for 5 classes of objects (including the background i.e. labelled as class 0, other object regions are labelled as class 1,2,..4).

I tried applying Con-Decon Architecture on this training data set using Caffe. But the problem that is happening IMHO is that there is a strong bias towards class 0 in the actual output as most of the region in my sliding window training is the background. Hence, it is classifying all the pixels in the actual output as Class 0 that is background and is unable to detect other HTML objects of Class labels 1,2,..4 on the test images that I supply to the network.

Any idea how to work around this problem?

Comment: you can try penalizing the loss function when it picks class 0. Or just balance your training data

Comment: I have created 2 patch sets for training, i.e. 1st set contains only the patches which have atleast one html objects in them. 2nd set contains patches which don't contain any objects in them. I am supplying all the patches of first set for training but only 5% of second set for training so as to limit the number of patches without objects going into the network. But this approach didn't help much in improving the model.

Comment: You are dealing with an imbalanced dataset, there are some strategies that might help you in this answer: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193887/classification-with-a-neural-network-when-one-class-has-disproportionately-many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is present in a lot of real world datasets as well.

One way of solving it would be to present your non-background data (classes 1,2,3...) to the neural network more times than you present the background data. This can be done by artificially duplicating the data of which you have fewer samples.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could also set:

```
ignore_label: 0
```

That might help.

Comment: I will try this approach and check. Thank you.